# Find div class string that contains x, and then change url of another div class within the parent div class

Tags: jquery, html

Im very new to html, java. I am trying to change a url (image) based on a string in a div class. 
Here is the Inspected Element:

```
<div class="container">

    ::before
    <div class="row">
        ::before
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="adsense"></div>
            <div class="maincontent">
                <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                <div id="schedules" class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
                    <div class="header schedule clearfix">
                        ::before
                        <h1></h1>
                        <div class="sub-menu left "></div>

    <div class="subheader schedule clearfix"></div>
    ::after

</div>
<div id="scores">

    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix">
        ::before
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 home-team"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 at"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 away-team text-right"></div>
        ::after
    </div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix"></div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix"></div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix"></div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix"></div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix">
        ::before
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 home-team">
            <div class="hometeamlogo" style="background-image: url("/img/m25/left/339.png");"></div>
            <div class="name">

                Barons 

            </div>
            <div class="record"></div>

                    WK 2  
                </div>
```

I am trying this code to change the background image url, based on if "barons" is found.

```
$('.maincontent').has('name:contains("Barons")').find('.hometeamlogo').attr('sty‌​le', 'background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/0YEAZo6.png");');
```

It isn't working. Now if it is easier just to write the code to replace this specific url (/img/m25/left/339.png), Im all for that too. But Id really like to get the the image to be changed.

Comment: I can't help but feel like you're not using your tools to the best advantage. Do you have access and ability to change the html? If so, I'd highly recommend giving your div that contains `Barons` an id or class that you could use as a selector. This just smells of bad practice to me. Otherwise, I'd suspect @RobinCarloCatacutan has an answer that will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an element that contains a certain text by using

`$( "div:contains('Text To Look')")`.

Check this out:

```js
var teamLogoElement = $( "div:contains('Barons')").parent(".home-team").find('.hometeamlogo');

teamLogoElement.attr("style","background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff)");
```

```css
.hometeamlogo {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">


    <div class="row">

        <div id="header"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="adsense"></div>
            <div class="maincontent">
                <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                <div id="schedules" class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
                    <div class="header schedule clearfix">
                  
                        <h1></h1>
                        <div class="sub-menu left "></div>

    <div class="subheader schedule clearfix"></div>


</div>
<div id="scores">

    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix">
    
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 home-team"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 at"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 away-team text-right"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix"></div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix"></div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix"></div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix"></div>
    <div class="scheduleweek clearfix">
   
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 home-team">
            <div class="hometeamlogo" style="background-image: url("/img/m25/left/339.png");"></div>
            <div class="name">

                Barons 

            </div>
            <div class="record"></div>

                    WK 2  
                </div>
```